# Xamarin bound Entry (double) confuses decimal symbol when saving/retrieving to/from SQL Database (EF6)

Tags: asp.net-web-api, xamarin.forms, entity-framework-6, cultureinfo, decimal-point

I am a newbie and I am building an app with Xamarin Forms where I save and get the data with asp.net Web API using EF6.

My system is in German, so the decimal sign is a ",". And here comes my Problem:

I have got an bound entry field "height":

XAML:

```
<Entry Placeholder="{helper:Translate Height}" Text="{Binding Height,Mode=TwoWay}" Keyboard="Numeric" Style="{StaticResource entryStyle}" >
                        <Entry.Behaviors>
                            <Behaviors:NumericEntry Double="True"/>
                        </Entry.Behaviors>
                    </Entry>
```

Model:

```
 public class ProfileData : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(propertyName)));
        }
.
.
.
        private double? _height;
        public double? Height
        {
            get => _height;
            set
            {
                _height = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
.
.
.
}
```

The binding works, but if I enter into the field a value like 175,2 and put a breakpoint on the setter in the model, there is a value of 1752....which gets saved like this into the DB (float column). If I enter a value like 175.2 its gets into the DB as 175,2 (notice the different Decimal Symbols). So if I get the values back from the DB, there will be 175,2 in my entry field, which, if I save again, turns like above into 1752.

Is this a problem of Culture Info? I tried for example to play with TryParse and changing the Culture Info in app.xaml.cs. but then my Weekdays get English too and the date format gets changed, which I don't want.

Could this also be a problem of the Web API and JSON?

I hope I do not have to (since I think this can't be the right solution) do something like `.replace(",",".")` or similar everywhere.

### Edit

The Behavior I am using comes from here:
https://github.com/xamarinhq/xamu-infrastructure/blob/master/src/XamU.Infrastructure/Behaviors/NumericValidationBehavior.cs

Comment: where does `Behaviors:NumericEntry` come from?  It seems likely that it is the root cause of the problem.

Comment: @Jason i got it from here: https://github.com/xamarinhq/xamu-infrastructure/blob/master/src/XamU.Infrastructure/Behaviors/NumericValidationBehavior.cs

Comment: I'd debug `OnEntryTextChanged` and see if it properly obeying your Culture settings

Comment: @Jason I did that, the culture in the TryParse method is the right one if i set a breakpoint.

Comment: to exclude the possibility that it comes from the behavior, i removed it, still same problem